# Разбить строку на несколько переменных

Tags: c++, строки

Есть строки вида 
`2 -58.0`
`12 -35.0`
`1 -8.0`
у них динамическая длина. Мне нужно вынуть эти два значения как 2 разных переменных первое число как `button`, второе как `value` (вместе со знаком).
Как мне это сделать?  перелистал кучу форумов, как думаете, этот код сойдёт?

```
int main()
{
    string button, value;
    string text = s_Text;
    stringstream ss;ss.str(text);
    ss >> button >> value;
    cout << button << endl;
    cout << value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что мешает проверить, сойдёт этот код или нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В качестве подхода решения данной задачи можно использовать ваш код примерно таким образом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::string record = "2 -58.0 12 -35.0 1 -8.0";

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> v;

    std::istringstream is( record );
    std::string button, value;

    while ( is >> button >> value ) v.emplace_back( button, value );

    for ( const auto &p : v ) std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
2: -58.0
12: -35.0
1: -8.0
```

Или можно использовать числовые объекты:

```
//...

int main()
{
    std::string record = "2 -58.0 12 -35.0 1 -8.0";

    std::vector<std::pair<int, double>> v;

    std::istringstream is( record );
    int button;
    double value;

    while ( is >> button >> value ) v.emplace_back( button, value );

    for ( const auto &p : v ) std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод на консоль будет таким же, как показано выше

```
2: -58
12: -35
1: -8
```